# Import Vector Graphics generated in Inkscape to Coreldraw X3

Tags: pdf, inkscape, coreldraw

I always use Inkscape (version 0.91) to generate my Vector graphics and then export them to either .pdf/.png/.eps or other file formats, depending on the need.

My Prof. however expects us to send all the files in the Corel X3 format, hence my question:

What is the best way to import vector graphics generated in Inkscape to Corel X3, so that I can save them as X3 Corel draw files with minimal loss of information?

Answer (score 0):

save as a plain SVG in inkscape not inkscape SVG
depends how complex the vector file is for simple ones PDF would be ok also

Comment: I tried plain SVG, which was not working at all. PDF gave reasonable results, however transparency got lost and it only works when text is converted to paths. That is still quite inconvenient. For now, I really just export to PDF with text converted to paths, but it would be better to have a loss free conversion. It's quite sad that vector graphics can not be exchanged easily...